# Sheet referring to a Google response sheet loses integrity

Tags: forms, google-sheets, response, publish

I have a Google form. The result goes to a response sheet.

I want to publish some of that info, so I make another sheet that refers to the response sheet (references like ='Form Responses1'!B5)

I have users that us a Google Sheet to get the published info, using =ImportRange.

When I set it up, it all works great (after it syncs).

The problem: one set of users that is allowed access to the form responses need to fix data in the response sheet, e.g., incorrect spelling, phone#s, duplicate entry. They've been doing this for a while and seemingly working.

But if I look at my sheet to be published after a day or so, it is broken. Where previously it went sequentially in one column like:

```
='Form Responses 1'!B5
='Form Responses 1'!B6
='Form Responses 1'!B7
='Form Responses 1'!B8
='Form Responses 1'!B9
```

it somehow gets off, and some items will be missing, like

```
='Form Responses 1'!B5
='Form Responses 1'!B7
='Form Responses 1'!B9
='Form Responses 1'!B10
='Form Responses 1'!B11
```

For the last couple of days, I go in and manually fix it by copying the formulas down, but it gets off again the next day.

Anyone seen this? Recommendations?  Thanks!